# Parallelize inner for loop in R function

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing

I am building a Markov Chain Monte Carlo sampler in R, the idea behind that is that I have a population of Chains that are updated in parallel (independently) and at some point they interact.
What I want to do is to parallelize the independent update since the whole code takes a long time to be executed.
However, foreach doesn't seem to be appropriate since it must return values, I just need to update them, does anybody had this problem and came up with a smart solution?

```
population_MCMC <- function(niter, burnin,thin ,th0, T_N ,Sig, y0, log_target)
{ 
  # th0 will be updated at each step, th will contain the output of interest (that is, when T_N = 1)
  th <- matrix(nrow= ceiling((niter-burnin)/thin), ncol=2)

  nacp = 0 # number of accepted moves

  for(i in 1:(niter))
  {
      for(j in 1:length(T_N)){ # <-- THIS IS THE FOR LOOP I WANT TO PARALLELIZE!

          #this is the local change
          delta = as.vector(rmvnorm(1, mean = th0[j,], sig = Sig))
          lacp <- log_target(th = delta, y_obs = y_obs, y0 = y0, t_n=T_N[j])
          lacp <- lacp - log_target(th = th0[j,], y_obs = y_obs, y0 = y0, t_n=T_N[j])
          #cat(lacp,"\n")
          lgu <- log(runif(1))  
          if(!(is.na(lacp)) & lgu < lacp)
          {
            th0[j,] <- delta
            nacp = nacp + 1
          }
      }

    # Try to exchange theta_l and theta_m where m = l+1 or m= l-1 if l=! 1 and l=! length(T_N)
    ..... some other markovian stuff .....

    if(i>burnin & (i-burnin)%%thin==0){
      th[(i-burnin)/thin,] = th0[length(T_N),]
    }

    if(i%%1000==0) cat("*** Iteration number ", i,"/", niter, "\n")
  }
  cat("Acceptance rate =", nacp/niter, "\n")
  return(th)
}
```

EDIT: if it can be useful for benchmarking, you can get a running version of my code here

https://github.com/mariob6/progetto_bayes/blob/master/population_basedMC.R
requires this source file 
https://github.com/mariob6/progetto_bayes/blob/master/simple_oscillator.R

Comment: How about `parLapply` from the parallel package.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any particular problem with parallelizing an inner loop as long as there are enough tasks for your workers and they take a reasonable amount of compute time. Parallelizing the outer loop is usually more efficient, but if the outer loop can't be safely parallelized then you parallelize the inner.

Restructuring your code to allow data structures to be properly updated can be tricky. In this case, I suggest that the body of the foreach loop return a list that indicates how the corresponding row of "th0" should be updated so that the combine function (which executes on the master) can perform the actual update.

Here's a stripped down example that demonstrates this technique:

```
example <- function() {
  th0 <- matrix(0, 4, 4)
  nacp <- 0

  updatemaster <- function(ignore, ...) {
    for (r in list(...)) {
      if (! is.null(r$delta)) {
        cat('updating row', r$j, '\n')
        th0[r$j,] <<- r$delta
        nacp <<- nacp + 1
      } else {
        cat('not updating row', r$j, '\n')
      }
    }
    NULL  # combine function called strictly for side effect
  }

  for (i in 1:2) {
    ignore <-
      foreach(j=1:nrow(th0), .combine='updatemaster',
              .init=NULL, .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
        delta <- rnorm(ncol(th0))
        if (rnorm(1) >= 0)
          list(j=j, delta=delta)
        else
          list(j=j, delta=NULL)
      }

    print(th0)
    print(nacp)
  }
}

suppressMessages(library(doSNOW))
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(2)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
example()
```

This could be improved by only sending a chunk of "th0" to each of the workers once and then reusing it for every iteration of the outer loop. That could reduce the overhead significantly, but gets significantly more complicated as well.